# PhantomJS Error: PhantomJS is a headless WebKit with JavaScript API has stopped working

Tags: javascript, debugging, selenium, phantomjs

I am currently running version 1.9.8.0 PhantomJS.  My problem is it works fine and does what it should (which in my case is going through the site counting certain elements to start off with) but I got this error:

```
PhantomJS is a headless WebKit with JavaScript API has stopped working.
```

The full error is:

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: PhantomJS.exe
  Application Version:  1.9.8.0
  Application Timestamp:    5449270a
  Fault Module Name:    PhantomJS.exe
  Fault Module Version: 1.9.8.0
  Fault Module Timestamp:   5449270a
  Exception Code:   c0000005
  Exception Offset: 00057976
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
  Locale ID:    2057
  Additional Information 1: 8236
  Additional Information 2: 823646afcac85a21ce127aeb0b347bb5
  Additional Information 3: 137e
  Additional Information 4: 137ec742f6481348348abf863da72fd4

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```

It only seems to happen on one retailer site (currys) as I have it running on other retailers and it works fine.  Also it always breaks on currys and it is since they have updated their site.  If anyone could help it would be much appreciated.

Here is a code snippet:

```
var options = new PhantomJSOptions();
            options.AddAdditionalCapability("phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.124 Safari/537.36");
            options.AddAdditionalCapability("phantomjs.page.settings.loadImages", "false");
            options.AddAdditionalCapability("phantomjs.page.settings.resourceTimeout", "12000");
            PhantomJSDriverService service = PhantomJSDriverService.CreateDefaultService(PhantomJSPath);
            service.HideCommandPromptWindow = false;//make it true on deployment
            using (PhantomJSDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver(service, options))
            {

                driver.Manage().Window.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1920, 989);
                ITakesScreenshot screenShot = driver as ITakesScreenshot;
                IJavaScriptExecutor jse = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;

                try
                {
                    CAInformationProviderConfiguration.CAInformationSources.ForEach(source =>
                    {
                        DefaultCAInformationSourceResult result = new DefaultCAInformationSourceResult();
                        result.CAInformationSource = source;
                        try
                        {

                            driver.ExecutePhantomJS(
@"
    var page = this;
    page.onResourceRequested = function(requestData, networkRequest) {
        //console.log(requestData.url);
        if (requestData.url.match(/(.*ajax\.html.*)|(.*facebook.*)|(.*twitter.*)|(.*instagram.*)|(.*youtube.*)|(.*hotukdeals.*)|(.*pinterest.*)|(.*flix360.*)/)) {
            networkRequest.abort();
        }

    };
        page.onResourceReceived = function(response) {
          //console.log('loaded ' +  response.url+'\n'+ response.stage) ;
        };

");
                            //scrape
                            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(source.Url);
```

it will then loop through checking elements on the page.
**Edit**

I upgraded to v2.0 PhantomJS and I am getting the same issue.

I should mention I m using PhantomJS with Selenium.

what is the best way to restart PhantomJS - I was thinking if I could restart it after it has processed a certain amount of rows it may prevent the application crashing?

RESOLUTION:

It seems that the memory usage was building up for this and when it got over 1gb it crashed.  To stop this from happening I ended up looping through a batch and then restarting phantomjs.  Not ideal but fixes my issue for now.

Thanks

Comment: Could you show the script ran by phantomjs? A simple render() does work for me on 1.9.2 on mac os

Comment: Seems to be a bug with PhantomJS. Try updating to PhantomJS 2. Also, if you seek debugging help, you should provide code that you have trouble with.

Comment: Is this related to the version problem?

Comment: I can't see this issue on the release notes and its seems strange that generally it works but just for the one retailer it stops working after it has run for a while

Comment: I am just trying version 2.0 locally to see if I get the same error...